# Read concurrently running pthreads' local data in another pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have invoked pthread (suppose 10 threads) from main and want to access in 1 of the threads, the local data of all those pthreads (from remaining 9) which are concurrently running with this 1st thread. For this first i need to check which all threads are active at that moment and then access its local data. Is there any way I can do this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a mutex to prevent simultaneous access to data by more than a thread.

Threads do not have local data. The process to which the threads belong to has these data memory pages assigned to it. All threads can freely access any part of memory within the process. Now, that might cause problems if data structures are accessed simultaneously by more than a thread. That's why synchronization is needed.

Comment: No the data is not shared data.. I need to access other threads' local data and also check which threads are alive simultaneously..